# 12 months dynamic array based on current month

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to build an array of 12 months based on current month, so of current month is march my array should look like:

```
const months =[“March”, “February”, “January”, “December”, “November”, “October”] etc, all the way to 12 previous months
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, create an array with the months and adjust it based on the current month

```js
const 
    months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    month = (new Date()).getMonth(),
    previous = months.splice(0, month);
// if you have to use this in a front-end app, you might want to use .concat(...) instead of the spread operator
const output = [...previous.reverse(), ...months.reverse()]
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically without an initial array using [`Date#toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to retrieve month names.

This gives you access to localization automatically by accepting a [locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#locale_identification_and_negotiation) as a parameter. It should be noted that this will use the local system timezone, you'll need to adjust if you want UTC.

```js
function getPriorTwelveMonths({ date = new Date(), locale = 'default' } = {}) {
  const monthName = (date) => date.toLocaleString(locale, { month: 'long' });

  date.setDate(15);

  const month = date.getMonth();
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    date.setMonth((month - i + 12) % 12);
    result.push(monthName(date));
  }

  return result;
}

const defaults = getPriorTwelveMonths();
// pass a locale
const korean = getPriorTwelveMonths({ locale: 'ko-KR' });
// or a date and locale
const frenchDec1995 = getPriorTwelveMonths({
  date: new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00'),
  locale: 'fr',
});

console.log(`[${defaults.join(',')}]`);
console.log(`[${korean.join(',')}]`);
console.log(`[${frenchDec1995.join(',')}]`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
let curMonth = 'Mar', ctr = 0, ref = months.indexOf(curMonth), sorted = [];
while (ctr <= 11) {
  let n = ref - ctr
  n = n >= 0 ? n : 11 + n;
  let m = months[n]
  sorted.push(m)
  ctr++;
}
console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
const currentMonth = "March";

// First find current month index
const currentMonthIndex = months.findIndex((item) => currentMonth === item)

// Then reorder the array
const orderedMonths = months.slice(currentMonthIndex).concat(months.slice(0, currentMonthIndex));
console.log('orderedMonths', orderedMonths);
```

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uot8Lfdr/2/

Answer (score 0):

Using the array prototype methods, concat, splice, and reverse, you can manipulate a list of months to produce the array you want.

You can get the current month as a number using new Date().getMonth()

```js
const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

const offsetReverseMonths = months.concat(...months.splice(0, new Date().getMonth())).reverse();
console.log(offsetReverseMonths);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over how the months are defined, you could define them backwards to start, and avoid using `reverse()`, or other loops.

```
const months = ["December", "November", "October", "September", "August", "July", "June", "May", "April", "March", "February", "January"];
const monthSpot = 12 - new Date().getMonth() - 1;
const result = [...months.splice(monthSpot, 12), ...months];
console.log(result);
```